# Getting element ID's for if/else statements

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement, getelementbyid, window.open

Working on a project. I need the else statement to work but when I hit the submit button it just redirects to the "if"

```
<head>
<script>
    var judgmentAmount = document.getElementById('judgmentAmount');
    var amountCollected = document.getElementById('amountCollected');
    function judgmentCalc() {
        if( judgmentAmount - amountCollected < 10000 ) {
            window.open( 'http://afjudgment.com' );
        }else {
            window.open( 'http://www.yahoo.com' );
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Application</h1>
<p>I understand that this application neither obligates me to <b>Affirmative     Judgment</b> nor does it obligate <b>Affirmative Judgment</b> to me.</p>
<h3>Judgment Information</h3>
<form>
    <span>Do you have a case number?</span>
    <input type="text" name="caseNumber" />
    <span>Amount of Judgment</span>
    <input type="text" name="judgmentAmount" id="judgmentAmount"  />
    <span>Amount collected to date</span>
    <input type="text" name="amountCollected" id="amountCollected"  />
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" onclick="judgmentCalc();" />
</form>
```

Comment: So, you debugged this, right? Place a breakpoint on the `var judgmentAmount` line, and stepping over it, examine the value of the variable. You'll find that it is an `HTMLInputElement`, not the value you were expecting. That would alert you that you need to take the value of that element before doing the comparison.

Comment: See this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ova74kmh/ in my answer. It works as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to operate with values of your elements:

```
function judgmentCalc() {

  var judgmentAmount = +document.getElementById('judgmentAmount').value;
  var amountCollected = +document.getElementById('amountCollected').value;

  if( judgmentAmount - amountCollected < 10000 ) {
    window.open( 'http://afjudgment.com' );
  } 
  else {
    window.open( 'http://www.yahoo.com' );
  }
}
```

var `judgmentAmount = document.getElementById('judgmentAmount')` returns only a reference to element with ID "judgmentAmount". If you want to use element's value, you need to do this:

`var judgmentAmount = document.getElementById('judgmentAmount').value`.

The next step is calculating some amount. You need to convert string to int (with `+` operator)

```
typeof judgmentAmount; // "string"

typeof +judgmentAmount; // "number"
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ova74kmh/)

Answer (score 0):

You are only comparing the objects, you need to compare their values

```
var judgmentAmount = Number(document.getElementById('judgmentAmount').value);
var amountCollected = Number(document.getElementById('amountCollected').value);
```

Also, convert them to Number before comparison.

```
function judgmentCalc() {
    var judgmentAmount = Number(document.getElementById('judgmentAmount').value);
    var amountCollected = Number(document.getElementById('amountCollected').value);
    if( judgmentAmount - amountCollected < 10000 ) {
        window.open( 'http://afjudgment.com' );
    }else {
        window.open( 'http://www.yahoo.com' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. These lines are outside of the `judgementCalc` function, so would never be updated before clicking `Save`

Comment: @jasonscript you are right, I missed out on that one. Thanks

Comment: The `Number` is unnecessary at least in this case.

Comment: @torazaburo sure, but `at least in this case` is the operative phrase here. In another context, if OP choose to do `judgmentAmount + amountCollected` instead of `judgmentAmount - amountCollected` we may see another question as to why `judgmentAmount + amountCollected` isn't working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access values of these input fields instead of directly working on dom elemens returned by `document.getElementById()`. You can get value of `input` using `.value` property.

```
var judgmentAmount = document.getElementById('judgmentAmount').value;
var amountCollected = document.getElementById('amountCollected').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

move your variables inside the function so they are properly filled at the time of function execution, and add .value properties of the DOM elements.

try this:

```
    function judgmentCalc() {
      var judgmentAmount = document.getElementById('judgmentAmount').value;
      var amountCollected = document.getElementById('amountCollected').value;
        if( judgmentAmount - amountCollected < 10000 ) {
            window.open( 'http://afjudgment.com' );
        }else {
            window.open( 'http://www.yahoo.com' );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the HTML DOM elements here:

```
var judgmentAmount = document.getElementById('judgmentAmount');
var amountCollected = document.getElementById('amountCollected');
```

So in your `judgementCalc` method you need to get the values of those elements:

```
function judgmentCalc() {
    // notice that we're using VALUE here:
    if( judgmentAmount.value - amountCollected.value < 10000 ) {
        window.open( 'http://afjudgment.com' );
    }else {
        window.open( 'http://www.yahoo.com' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please run the script below, it'll work fine:

```
<head>
<script>
    function judgmentCalc() {
        var judgmentAmount = document.getElementById('judgmentAmount').value;
        var amountCollected = document.getElementById('amountCollected').value;

        var exp = parseFloat(judgmentAmount) - parseFloat(amountCollected);

        if( exp < 10000 ) {
            window.open( 'http://afjudgment.com' );
        } else {
            window.open( 'http://www.yahoo.com' );
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Actually, the `parseFloat` is not necessary, since the subtraction will coerce the value to a number.

Answer (score -1):

You have to compare the value of the input element, Please try the following

```
function judgmentCalc() {
    var judgmentAmount = document.getElementById('judgmentAmount').value;
    var amountCollected = document.getElementById('amountCollected').value;

    if( (judgmentAmount - amountCollected) < 10000 ) {
        window.open( 'http://afjudgment.com' );
    } else {
        window.open( 'http://www.yahoo.com' );
    }
}
```

It may help you.